# Complex Eigenvectors for complex eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm having trouble with the following matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}2 & 1 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\1 & 2 & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

I've already calculated the eigenvalues $(3, 1+i, 1-i)$ and the eigenvector for Eigenvalue=3, but I'm having real trouble getting the complex eigenvectors. I've tried an online calculator, but the method seems overly complex and I feel like I've I've missed a trick somewhere.

Can anyone help?

Cheers!

Andy

Edit: I've got as far as figuring out that $y_1 = -y_2$ for $(A-xI)y=0$; $x=(1+i) $ but i get no further

Edit 2: Not sure I'm making myself clear enough. I understand *how* I can solve for the complex Eigenvectors, but don't seem to be able to do it. I really feel like I missed something.

Edit 3: OK. Starting from $$\begin{bmatrix}2-(1+i) & 1 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\1 & 2-(1+I) & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & 1-(1+i)\end{bmatrix}$$

Then $$\begin{bmatrix}1-i & 1 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\1 & 1-i & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -i\end{bmatrix}$$

I combined the first and second rows to eliminate $y_3$ to find that $y_1=-y_2$.

After that I tried substituting $y_1$ with$-y_2$ in every row but then can only solve for $y_3$
in terms of $y_2$ which I also don't know.

It has just occurred to me to try to add/subtract the substituted rows to try to eliminate $y_2$.

I'm on my phone so that took ages to type!

Comment: Just proceed like in the real case, you have to solve the linear system (A-x1)y=0 while setting x=3

Comment: My problem is in solving $(A-xI)y=0$ with $x=(1+i)$. I know i only need to solve for one, as the other is the complex conjugate, but i just can't seem to do it

Comment: What did you try to solve $(A-(1+i)I)X=0$ for the vector $X$?

Comment: Yup. See the comment above..

Comment: Whatever method you use for solving systems of linear equations with real coefficients, use that same method for solving systems of linear equations with coefficients.

Comment: If you understand how, but you can't do it, then you don't understand how. Why not edit in what you have done, so we can tell you where you've gone wrong, or how you can get unstuck.

Comment: Since the eigenvector is not unique, we are free to choose the first non-zero component to be 1.  So, we set $y_1=1$ and see if we get a solution for $y_2$ and $y_3$.  If no, then $y_1$ is zero.  If we require a normalized eigenvector, we choose the first non-zero component to be real.  We can still multiply by all the components by an overall phase factor of $e^{i\theta}$ if we want without changing the normalization.  If we wanted to choose some other non-zero component to be 1 instead of the first, that is okay, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is just a matter of obtaining the reduced row echelon form of the matrix. This is a standard technique for solving for the kernel of a matrix. Finding the kernel of $det(A - \lambda I)$ gives you the eigenvector associated with the eigenvalue $\lambda$. Since the eigenvector is complex, the other complex eigenvector is the complex conjugate of the first. Therefore, we only need to solve for one.

Using $\lambda = 1 + i$,

\begin{bmatrix}
        1-i & 1 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
        1 & 1-i & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
        -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -i \\
        \end{bmatrix}

Add the second row to the first, and multiply the bottom row by $-\sqrt{2}$:

\begin{bmatrix}
        2-i & 2-i & 0 \\
        1 & 1-i & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
        1 & -1 & i\sqrt{2} \\
        \end{bmatrix}
multiply the top row by $\frac{1}{5}(2+i)$

\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 1-i & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
        1 & -1 & i\sqrt{2} \\
        \end{bmatrix}

subtract the first row from the other two rows:

\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & -i & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
        0 & -2 & i\sqrt{2} \\
        \end{bmatrix}
multiply second row by $i$:

\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & -\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} \\
        0 & -2 & i\sqrt{2} \\
        \end{bmatrix}

subtract the second row from the first, and add 2 times the second row to the third:

\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} \\
        0 & 1 & -\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
This is the reduced row echelon form. Therefore, the eigenvector associated with $\lambda = 1 + i$ is:

\begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\
        -1 \\
        i \sqrt{2}  \\
        \end{bmatrix}

and so the eigenvector associated with $\lambda = 1-i$ is:

\begin{bmatrix}
        1 \\
        -1 \\
        -i \sqrt{2}  \\
        \end{bmatrix}